# Getting error : : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deps') while running angular test file

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

Please find the describe in test file :
`

```
fdescribe('NdelDeviceBalancePayoffComponent', () => {
    let component: NdelDeviceBalancePayoffComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<NdelDeviceBalancePayoffComponent>;
    let ndelUpgradeService: NdelUpgradeService;
    let mockNdelUpgradeService: Partial<NdelUpgradeService> = {
        setScanImei(): void {
            // mock implementation
        }
    }
    let mockLineDeviceService: Partial<LineDeviceService> = {
    }

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [NdelDeviceBalancePayoffComponent],
            imports: [HttpClientModule],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: NdelUpgradeService,
                    useValue: mockNdelUpgradeService
                },
                ,
                {
                    provide: LineDeviceService,
                    useValue: mockLineDeviceService
                },
                HttpService, HttpHeader, HttpTrackService, HttpLoaderService, HttpClient, HttpHandler
            ],
              schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NdelDeviceBalancePayoffComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        ndelUpgradeService = TestBed.inject(NdelUpgradeService);
    });

    it('should create component NdelDeviceBalancePayoffComponent', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

`[image]

Getting Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deps').
"deps" is not used anywhere in spec file and test file.

Comment: You should provide `HttpClientTestingModule` instead of `HttpClientModule`. You should not hit the network and the API in your unit tests

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Updated with HttpClientTestingModule, but still am seeing the same error mentioned